# Apply CSS to a particular page element in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Is there a Firefox extension that will let me simply select a visible element on a page, get a CSS selector referring specifically to that element (as the Firefox Web Developer extension already does), and the TYPE IN SOME CSS that is immediately applied to that selector?

For example:

I have a page with some yellow text.  I want to change the yellow text to red.

I want to be able to simply click on the yellow text, see that it can be referenced by the long and cumbersome CSS selector

```
#firsthalf.foo li #crazystuff .wishfulthinking b a #badidea
```

and then say

```
color: red !important;
```

and see the text turn red.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Firebug will do just that.

[image: Firebug]